# NonLinearModelFit with Two Dimensional List of Weights

Tags: syntax, fitting

I'm currently trying to fit Planck's law (`B[λ, T]`) to measurements, thereby determining Planck's constant.

I have a list of triplets containing wavelength, temperature and measured intensity and a list of triplets with their errors, like:

```
datalist  = {{λ1, T1, B1}, {λ2, T2, B2}, ...}    
errorlist = {{σλ1, σT1, σB1}, {σλ2, σT2, σB2}, ...}
```

Although `NonlinearModelFit` can fit functions of the type `R2 → R`, it seems to only accept a one dimensional list as `Weights`. This is what I tried:

```
NonlinearModelFit[datalist, B[λ, T], {{h, hlit}}, {λ,T}, Weights -> (errorlist)^-2]
```

I could of course propagate the partial uncertainties to create one uncertainty for each triplet, thereby have a one dimensional `Weights` list instead, but it seems a bit unethic.

Would it be possible to fit Planck's curve to my measurements without having to combine the errors first?

**Edit**: Here's the exact error message that I get:

> NonlinearModelFit::wts: The value of option Weights -> {{100.,100.,2500.},{11.1111,25.,25.},{11.1111,2.77778,11.1111}} should be a list of real numbers or a pure function. >>

(I used this data and function as an example: http://pastebin.com/pqxDfe4u)

Comment: please post a link to your data and error?

Comment: Hi chris, I've included the error message and some example data in the original post. (I'm actually fitting the ratio of two Planck functions, so included an example function to keep things simple.)

Comment: it seems this works: `NonlinearModelFit[datalist, F[x, y], {{a, 2}}, {x, y} , 
 Weights -> Last/@(errorlist)]` but may be you want errors in x and y as well?

Comment: Yes, i would like to include all the uncertainties. If plotted, it would look like every data point is surrounded by a cube, instead of a line normal to the λT-plane.

Comment: What I have done in the past is simply to multiply the reciprocal variances in the abscissa and the ordinate together and use that as a weight. Of course, that is not strictly correct, but it will be a reasonable approximation if the residuals are small. If you want it done strictly correctly (i.e. through total least squares), `NonlinearModelFit` can't help you--you'll have to code it yourself.